# How can I add an item to the structure with vector elements?

Tags: c++, vector, structure, push-back

I would like to add the peak position of a vector and the peak number but I can't find a way to add the elements and then return it, or write it on console.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct PeakData {
      vector<int> pos, peaks;
};

PeakData pick_peaks(vector<int> v) {
   PeakData result;
   for (int i = 1; i < v.size() - 1; i++) {
       if ((v[i] > v[i - 1]) && (v[i] > v[i + 1])) {
           result.peaks.push_back(v[i]);
            result.pos.push_back(i);
        }
   }
        return result;
}
```

Example: pickPeaks([3, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3]) should return {pos: [3, 7], peaks: [6, 3]}

Comment: What's the problem with this code? It seems fine. Is the problem just how to print the data?

Comment: Other than your vector will be in reverse order from what you expect, it should give you the correct data. Just add a print routine to your PeakData struct to print the vectors.

Comment: @churill yes, the problem is that I don't know how to print the data.

Comment: @Pilv Please be more specific. What have you tried, in what way did it not work? You only need `std::cout <<` and a loop over your vectors to print it in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your main function:

```
int main()
{

    vector<int> a = {3, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3};
    PeakData stPickPeaks = pick_peaks(a);
    vector<int> :: iterator itr;
    for(itr = stPickPeaks.pos.begin(); itr<stPickPeaks.pos.end(); itr++)
    {
        cout <<*itr<<endl;
    }

    for(itr = stPickPeaks.peaks.begin(); itr<stPickPeaks.peaks.end(); itr++)
    {
        cout <<*itr<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also try to pass the parameters either by reference or pointer.

Comment: Please don't answer twice. You have the option to edit your answer, or delete this old one and keep the improved version :)